# codeigniter showing code as texts and 404 not found instead of view

Tags: php, codeigniter

when I run it shows this

[image]

and here is the controller :

```
<?php

class Try extends CI_Controller {
public function show(){
    //load model
    $this->load->model('try_model');

    //get object
    $model = $this->try_model;

    //get data from model
    $text = $model->kalimat;
    $judul = $model->title;

    //create data in the form of array
    $data= array(
        'title' => $judul,
        'teks' => $text
    );

    //load file view try_view.php
    $this->load->view('try_view',$data);
}
}
?>
```

the model :

```
 <?php
 class try_model extends CI_model {
//mendifinisikan properti dengan nama $kalimat
public $kalimat = 'Success!';
public $title = 'Percobaan MVC';
 }
?>
```

the view :

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>
   <?php echo $title?>
</title>
</head>
 <body>
    <h2> <?php echo $teks?></h2>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm still new to codeigniter, I was reading the tutorial and trying to make a 'Hellow World' kind of application but I modified some of it in order to further understand how this works but this is what happening to me

Comment: Class name shouldn't be a keyword. See you named the controller as try. Try is a keyword. Change the controller name and file name as well then try to execute.

Comment: laso, please try removing the `p` from `<?pphp` from your Controller

Comment: oh I didn't see that double p in the opening tag... thank you. @Naga thank you, I didn't know that...